# Replace value in JSON file with jq

Tags: jq

For flexibility reasons my file is layed out as an array of keys and values with different types:

```
{
 "keyPairs": [
  {
   "key": "first",
   "value": {
    "boolValue": false
   }
  },
  {
   "key": "second",
   "value": {
    "intValue": "1"
   }
  }
}
```

I want to replace one of the values in the file. I've already figured out how to read the value:

```
$ jq '.keyPairs[] | select(.key == "second") | .value.intValue' myfile.json
"1"
```

I can get it to change the output:

```
$ jq '.keyPairs[] | select(.key == "second") | .value.intValue = "0"' myfile.json
{
 "key": "second",
 "value": {
  "intValue": "0"
 }
}
```

But this just changes the output. How do I get the value in the file changed?

Note this is a minimal Linux distro so I only have access to limited tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring the assignment to top-level by enclosing traversal and filtering into parentheses, so the context stays the same on exit:

```bash
jq '(.keyPairs[] | select(.key == "second").value.intValue) = "0"' myfile.json
```

Saving into the same file is not supported directly, but you could either save into a temporary file and move it on success, or use tools like [sponge](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

```bash
jq '…' myfile.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json myfile.json
```